# How to bring a background process started by a script to foreground

Tags: command-line, java, process, remote, desktop-background

I have a server setup that runs some `java` servers but since I am not home all the time those servers are activated via a `.sh` script. But now I don't know how to bring the java background processes to the foreground if I want to change something

Comment: How did you run them in the background?

Comment: I have a webpage via wich I activate the servers. So I started the server via a `.sh` script and the `.sh` script is activated via a `.php` script on a webpage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forground a running process that was started with a script (MineCraft Server)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419787/forground-a-running-process-that-was-started-with-a-script-minecraft-server)