# Forground a running process that was started with a script (MineCraft Server)

Tags: server, scripts, process, minecraft

I have a MineCraft server starting with a script in `chrontab`. When I start my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Computer, and I SSH to the server, I want, for example, to add someone in the whitelist, but I need to have the process of the server running in the foreground, and somehow the `jobs -l` command does not show the process even though `htop` clearly shows it running with the process ID.

When I try to foreground the process ID of the program, it just says `-bash: fg: 1328: no such job` (1328 beeing the java job in this instance)

Can I even foreground the program so I can do commands like `/op`, `/kick` and or `whitelist add <name>` when I started the program trough a script in `chrontab`, or is that not possible?.

I might, also, add that the user is the same one, meaning that I want to foreground the process on the same user.

Comment: can you give the crontab entry and the script you use? You can also use gnu `screen` to start it, so that you can switch to the screen with the server anytime

Answer (score 1):

### Background:

You can, only, bring a process/program to the foreground in the same terminal in which it was initially sent to the background ... What you're asking about, on the other hand, is to detach and transfer a running process/program from its controlling terminal and  attach it to a new terminal ... That is a totally different matter and it's not easy(*for a normal user*) ... It gets even harder when that process has children(*sub processes under it*) ... The more the children the harder and more complicated it gets.

If your main process is started with a script file then you might want to get its PID this way:

```
pgrep -f "ScriptFileName.sh"
```

changing `ScriptFileName.sh` to your script's actual filename.

### Methods to consider:

#### First method

There is no guaranteed out of the box easy way to do this but, there are tools like [reptyr](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/reptyr.1.html)(*and others*) that try to do that using [ptrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace) ... `reptyr` is available in the Ubuntu repositories so you can install it like so:

```
sudo apt install reptyr
```

and try if it works for you ... It can be used like so:

```
reptyr PID
```

or like so:

```
reptyr -T PID
```

You **need**, however, to either change [ptrace_scope](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/Yama.txt) from `1`(*default but, will prevent `reptyr` from attaching processes*) to `0`(*Will revert back to `1` after reboot or you can set it back to `1` after you have finished for optimum security*) for `reptyr` to work like so:

```
echo "0" | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

or use `sudo` like so:

```
sudo reptyr PID
```

#### Second method

There are also ways of creating a named pipe and using [GDB](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/gdb.1.html) to attach it to the running process's STDIN or STDOUT in order to be able to write(*send arguments*) to or read(*see the output*) from that process but, this is, however a bit complicated and might not work as expected from the first time(*GDB is a source-level debugger and not a regular user program*) ... The process of doing this, however, looks something like this(*just for demonstration ... You will face issues ... figure them out yourself*):

- Create a named pipe for process's STDIN like so:

  ```
  mkfifo /tmp/in_pipe
  ```
- Create a named pipe for process's STDOUT like so:

  ```
  mkfifo /tmp/out_pipe
  ```
- Attache the process like so:

  ```
  sudo gdb -p PID
  ```
- Close the current process's STDIN like so:

  ```
   call close(0)
  ```
- Reopen the process's STDIN and attach it to the named pipe like so(*GDB might hang on this until the pipe is first used/written to, but follow the two steps below*):

  ```
  call open("/tmp/in_pipe", 0)
  ```
- From another terminal, write to the named pipe arguments you want to pass to the running process like so:

  ```
  echo "arg1 arg2 ..." > /tmp/in_pipe
  ```
- Notice, you might need to go back to GDB terminal and continue the process if it appears stopped like so:

  ```
  continue
  ```
- Close the current process's STDOUT like so:

  ```
   call close(1)
  ```
- Reopen the process's STDOUT and attach it to the named pipe like so(*GDB might hang on this until the pipe is first used/read from, but follow the two steps below*):

  ```
  call open("/tmp/out_pipe", 1)
  ```
- From another terminal, read the output of the running process from the named pipe like so:

  ```
  cat /tmp/out_pipe
  ```
- Notice, you might need to go back **again** to GDB terminal and continue the process if it appears stopped like so:

  ```
  continue
  ```

#### Third method

The file descriptors in a process's controlling terminal are available under `/proc/PID/fd/` and you can send arguments to your script/process through `/proc/PID/fd/0` with somthing like:

```
echo "arg1 arg2" > /proc/PID/fd/0
```

**only** if you chose to run your script/process to read from a pipe(*otherwise the arguments will only be sent to the STDIN of the controlling terminal but, will not be forwarded to the script/process*) initially with something like:

```
cat | scriptfile
```

You can also read the process's STDOUT from `/proc/PID/fd/1` with something like:

```
cat /proc/PID/fd/1
```

#### Fourth method(*tracing only*)

There is also [strace](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/strace.1.html) which you can use to trace the process like so:

```
sudo strace -p PID
```

or just to read the process's output like so:

```
sudo strace -p PID -e write
```