# Is it possible to see a python program working after it's launched by cron in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, python, cron

This is something that has perplexed me and maybe there's a way to do it, but if you are running a python program from terminal it shows all the outputs. However when I run the python from cron, there is no terminal launch. It says it's running in the task manager processes(i.e "background"), but how do you know? Other than it worked before you launched it.

Is there a way to open that process to see what it's literally doing? (Similar to if I had just  started it in terminal.)

Basically, it's should be "printing" out information, but where is it "printing"[outputing] it too? How do I see it? Can I open the running program to see what it's doing at this moment in time?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1419787