# How do I stop a job in the background from outputing to the terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, make, redirect, background-process

I ran `make` in the terminal for Kismet on my Pi and it's been outputting to the terminal every 10 to 15 seconds, regardless of it is being run in the background or not.

I tried using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and running `bg` command. Although the jobs command lists it as `Running` and lists the command as `make &` to indicate that it's in the background, the output is still coming to the terminal.

I also paused it again and then ran `bg; %+ >1 /dev/null` to try to send the `STDOUT` to `/dev/null`, but it is still outputting to the screen.

Is there a way to make a job run in the background and only get `STDERR` messages to the terminal?

Here is the output:

First Attempt:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 make
root@stormpi:/usr/local/kismet# jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 make
root@stormpi:/usr/local/kismet# bg
[1]+ make &
root@stormpi:/usr/local/kismet# jobs
[1]+  Running                 make &
root@stormpi:/usr/local/kismet# In file included from entrytracker.h:36,
                 from system_monitor.cc:33:
trackedelement.h: In member function ‘void tracker_element_core_vector<T, TT>::set(tracker_element_core_vector<T, TT>::const_iterator, tracker_element_core_vector<T, TT>::const_iterator) [with T = double; tracker_type TT = (tracker_type)22]’:
trackedelement.h:1553:18: note: parameter passing for argument of type ‘tracker_element_core_vector<double, (tracker_type)22>::const_iterator’ {aka ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const double*, std::vector<double> >’} changed in GCC 7.1
     virtual void set(const_iterator a, const_iterator b) {
                  ^~~
trackedelement.h:1553:18: note: parameter passing for argument of type ‘tracker_element_core_vector<double, (tracker_type)22>::const_iterator’ {aka ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const double*, std::vector<double> >’} changed in GCC 7.1
```

2nd Attempt:

```
jobs
[1]+  Running                 make &
root@stormpi:/usr/local/kismet# fg
make
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 make
root@stormpi:/usr/local/kismet# jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 make
root@stormpi:/usr/local/kismet# bg; %+ >1 /dev/null
[1]+ make &
make
g++ -std=gnu++17 -MM -MP -Wall -Wno-unknown-warning-option -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-unused-function -Wno-infinite-recursion -g -I. -fPIE -g -O2 -O3 -pthread -DKS_STR_ENCODING_NONE    -MT gpsgpsd_v3.cc.o gpsgpsd_v3.cc -MF gpsgpsd_v3.cc.d
g++ -std=gnu++17 -Wall -Wno-unknown-warning-option -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-unused-function -Wno-infinite-recursion -g -I. -fPIE -g -O2 -O3 -pthread -DKS_STR_ENCODING_NONE    -c gpsgpsd_v3.cc -o gpsgpsd_v3.cc.o
```

Comment: Redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null.  try using `make -- 2>&1 > /dev/null &`

Answer (score 2):

These messages you get are most likely printed to standard error and not standard output ... You can verify which is which by running `make` through `strace` like so:

```
strace -e write make ...
```

Then see the file descriptor(*the first argument in the `write()` call*) ... 2 is standard error and 1 is standard output.

To hide these messages, you might want to direct both standard output(*file descriptor 1*) and standard error(*file descriptor 2*) to `/dev/null`(*or to another file*) before the command gets executed but, like so:

```
make ... > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

And **not** like so:

```
make ... 2>&1 > /dev/null &
```

See [redirection in bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) ... **Specifically** this excerpt:

> Note that the order of redirections is significant. For example, the
> command
>
> `ls > dirlist 2>&1` directs both standard output (file descriptor 1) and
> standard error (file descriptor 2) to the file dirlist, while the
> command
>
> `ls 2>&1 > dirlist` directs only the standard output to file dirlist,
> because the standard error was made a copy of the standard output
> before the standard output was redirected to dirlist.

An alternate way for directing both STDOUT and STDERR in bash is using `&>` e.g. like so:

```
make ... &> /dev/null &
```

To direct STDOUT only, use just `>` e.g. like so:

```
make ... > /dev/null &
```

You might want to direct to a log file for later inspection instead of `/dev/null` and in this case you might want to use the append operator `>>` e.g. directing STDOUT like so:

```
make ... >> file.log &
```

Or direct both STDOUT and STDERR e.g. like so:

```
make ... &>> file.log &
```

**Side notes**:

1. `>1` when it gets executed as intended e.g. `command >1` (*`>1` in your `bg; %+ >1 /dev/null` example will not*) will direct standard output to an actual file named `1` in the current working directory.
2. To direct to a file descriptor `>&FDNUMBER` is used ... Where `FDNUMBER` is the number of the file descriptor e.g. `>&2`(*direct STDOUT to STDERR*) or `2>&1`(*direct STDERR to STDOUT*).
3. To manipulate and direct file descriptors of an already running process see different ways, **specifically** using GDB, in my answer to [Forground a running process that was started with a script (MineCraft Server)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1419787).

Comment: That makes so much more sense now! Thanks a lot for the incredible detail and the references!